# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^5-\sin(y^3)}{4x^4+3y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Are the next computations correct?
$$
0\leq \left|\frac{x^5-\sin(y^3)}{4x^4+3y^2}\right|
\leq\frac{|x^5|}{4x^4}+\frac{|y^3|}{3y^2}
=\frac{|x|}{4}+\frac{|y|}{3}
$$

Then, by squeeze theorem, the limit is zero.

Comment: in the second step just remove the mods around $x$ and $y$ because you opened them with plus sign  later it looks like this  $\frac{x^5-\sin(y^3)}{4x^4+3y^2}$$\leq\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{3}$

Comment: The second inequality holds true only for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, and not for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Comment: @Rigel yeah you are true he should also consider that

Comment: @Rigel Not really a problem: the final inequality also holds for $x=0$ or $y\ne0$ (but not both, of course).

Comment: Does the second inequality discard the paths that intersect the coordinate axes?. Furthermore, according to WolframAlpha the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

$$0\leq |\frac{x^5-\sin(y^3)}{4x^4+3y^2}|\leq\frac{|x^5|}{4x^4+3y^2}+\frac{|y^3|}{3y^2+4x^4} \leqslant\frac{|x|}{4}+\frac{|y|}{3} \leqslant \frac{|x|+|y|}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}}{3}\leqslant \frac{2(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{3}=\frac{2 \delta}{3}$$

If you take $\delta=\frac{3 \epsilon}{2}$ you have the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of your limit.

Also as for a second solution:

$$0\leq |\frac{x^5-\sin(y^3)}{4x^4+3y^2}|\leq\frac{|x^5|}{4x^4+3y^2}+\frac{|y^3|}{3y^2+4x^4}$$

Compute the limits $$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{|x^5|}{4x^4+3y^2}$$ $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{|y^3|}{3y^2+4x^4}$$

by taking polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos{\theta}$$ $$y=r\sin{\theta}$$